# grep file matching specific column

Tags: awk, grep

I want to keep only the lines in `results.txt` that matched the IDs in `uniq.txt` based on matches in column 3 of `results.txt`. Usually I would use `grep -f uniq.txt results.txt`, but this does not specify column 3.

uniq.txt

```
9606
234831
131
31313
```

results.txt

```
readID  seqID   taxID   score   2ndBestScore    hitLength       queryLength     numMatches
A00260:70:HJM2YDSXX:4:1111:15519:16720  NC_000011.10    9606    169     0       28      151     1
A00260:70:HJM2YDSXX:3:1536:9805:14841   NW_021160017.1  9606    81      0       24      151     1
A00260:70:HJM2YDSXX:3:1366:27181:24330  NC_014803.1     234831  121     121     26      151     3
A00260:70:HJM2YDSXX:3:1366:27181:24330  NC_014973.1     443143  121     121     26      151     3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `grep` in combination with `sed` to manipulate the input patterns and achieve what you're looking for

```sh
grep -Ef <(sed -e 's/^/^(\\S+\\s+){2}/;s/$/\\s*/' uniq.txt) result.txt
```

If you want to match `n`th column, replace 2 in above command with `n-1`

outputs

```
A00260:70:HJM2YDSXX:4:1111:15519:16720  NC_000011.10    9606    169     0       28      151     1
A00260:70:HJM2YDSXX:3:1536:9805:14841   NW_021160017.1  9606    81      0       24      151     1
A00260:70:HJM2YDSXX:3:1366:27181:24330  NC_014803.1     234831  121     121     26      151     3
```

Answer (score 4):

With your shown samples, please try following code.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{arr[$0];next} ($3 in arr)' uniq.txt results.txt
```

***Explanation:***

```
awk '                     ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                  ##Checking condition which will be TRUE when uniq.txt is being read.
  arr[$0]                 ##Creating arrar with index of current line.
  next                    ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
($3 in arr)               ##If 3rd field is present in arr then print line from results.txt here.
' uniq.txt results.txt    ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

***2nd solution:*** In case your field number is not set in results.txt and you want to search values in whole line then try following.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{arr[$0];next} {for(key in arr){if(index($0,key)){print;next}}}' uniq.txt results.txt
```